# Неправильный порядок применения стилей css

Tags: html, css

Так я загружаю стили:

```
<link href="/assets/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Если посмотреть на изображения(Инструмент разработчика chrome) видно что приоритет стилей из первого файла выше чем у второго. Почему такое происхоит? такое же не должно бить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать чтобы стили второго файла были приоритетнее?

Comment: А если поменять местами все равно первый `reset`?

Comment: Как раз так и должно быть......чтоб приоритет поменялся - поменяйте местами подключение стилей.......либо увеличивайте вес селектора  .......https://canonium.com/articles/css-understanding-weight-selectors

Comment: @Алексей Приоритетным должно быть как раз последний указанный стиль

Comment: Последний указанный, если у него вес такой же или больше

Comment: @Herrgott Все равно не изменился

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вес второго больше. Или вы не про размер файла?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А как это зависит от размера файла?

Comment: вес **СЕЛЕКТОРА** а не файла

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Даже так... спасибо, не знал

Comment: вот тут еще посмотрите http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie  там есть вроде веса

Comment: @Алексей Спасибо, прочитав первую статью понял про вес селектора и исправил. Решения: `.searchbar .search_field`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключение файлов правильное, кто ниже тот и весомей, но есть небольшое НО какие селекторы вы используете в файле сброса? Если вес селекторов выше в сбросах, то необходимо исправлять. Вот таблица приоритетов селекторов:

1.Самый высокий приоритет имеет атрибут style. Это правило перекрывает все селекторы описанные в стилях.
2.Второе место занимает присутствие ID в селекторе(#some-id).
3.Далее идут все атрибуты(в том числе и атрибут class) и псевдоклассы(pseudo-classes) в селекторе.
4.Самый низкий приоритет у селекторов с именами элементов и псевдоэлементами(pseudo-elements).

```
0               I       II              III
!important
style
                #id     .class          tags
                        :pseudo-class   ::pseudo-elements
                        [attributes]
```

В данном примере видно, что в сбросах используется селектор тега + селектор по атрибуту против селектора класса в стилях.